# How to use ruby splat operator? Can we do some operation on it?

Tags: ruby

The confusing case:

```
arr = [:one, :two]
attr_accessor *arr + [:three]
```

In this case, it seems that we do a `+` operation on the splat `*arr`. But, generally we can't perform any operation on splat. So this make me confused.

I prefer another case like this:

```
arr = [:one, :two]
attr_accessor *(arr << :three)
```

So, what's your opinion?

Comment: Note that the second example modifies the array `arr`, while the first one doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you got the precedence wrong. `*arr + [:three]` is `*(arr + [:three])`, so it splats three arguments onto `attr_accessor`. The result of a splat is not a Ruby value, so no operations can be done on it. It is not an operator in the same sense that `+` is operator. Whereas `+` is a method, this usage of `*` is not.

(There is no opinion here, only a fact on how Ruby works.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess the precedence should be what you said. But, I didn't find the theoretical basis in ruby. So, could please provide a link or something that show us the precedence definition. Thanks again.

Comment: As I said, it is not an operator, so it does not get traditional "precedence": it is a part of Ruby grammar. Take a look [here](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/yacc.html), at rules `WHEN_ARGS`, `MLHS`, `MRHS`, `CALL_ARGS`, `ARGLIST` (your case is `CALL_ARGS`, as arguments to `attr_accessor`). The rules say a star can precede an argument, where argument is any kind of expression (such as `arr + [:three]`).